# How to calculate interval time when same button clicked twice in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

There is one button JavaScript of jQuery; first time I press the button, after some seconds again I press the same button. How to calculate the interval time between the two presses of a same button. Please can anyone help?

Code I tried: this code down and up, how can I calculate for same button pressing?

```
 var startTime, endTime;
 $("#bu").on('mousedown', function () {
 startTime = new Date().getTime();
 });

 $("#bu").on('mouseup', function () {
 endTime = new Date().getTime();
 longpress = (endTime - startTime < 500) ? false : true;
 });
```

Comment: Do you want do catch double click?

Comment: are you looking for doubleclick event?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to calculate how long user has clicked on button, but you are saying that you want to calculate time between clicks. Which one do you want?

Comment: no not like that @Epsilon. i have the code to calculate long press that i uploaded above but i need how to calculate time interval when same button preesed twice

Comment: @GESVadamanappakkam You can find answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```js
var startTime;
$("#bu").on('click', function() {
  if(startTime) {
    alert( "Time difference: " + (new Date().getTime() - startTime) );
    startTime = undefined;
  } else {
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="bu" value="Click Me" />
```

Comment: for trible click how can we do @Samuel Liew

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x2utqzst/)**

```
var clicked=false,
    duration=0;
$('button').click(function(){
    if(!clicked){
        window.interval=setInterval(function(){
            duration+=5;
            $('p').text('duration is: '+duration+' milliseconds');
        },5);
        clicked=true;
        $(this).text('Click Me Again');
    }
    else{
        clearInterval(window.interval);
        clicked=false;
        duration=0;
        $(this).text('Click Me');
    }
});
```